# How to convert to a time series and plot a dataframe with each day as a variable or column?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to get a plot of the number of Cov-19 in Italy over time, and came across this [repository in GitHub](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19), and tried to subset the data for Italy as such:

```
require(RCurl)
require(foreign)
x = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv")
corona = read.csv(text = x, sep =",",header = T)
str(corona)
Italy <- corona[,corona$Country.Region=='Italy']
Italy <- corona[corona$Country.Region=='Italy',][1,5:ncol(corona)]
head(Italy)[,45:52]
```

which outputs:

```
> head(Italy)[,45:52]
   X3.6.20 X3.7.20 X3.8.20 X3.9.20 X3.10.20 X3.11.20 X3.12.20
17    4636    5883    7375    9172    10149    12462    12462
   X3.13.20
17    17660
```

Converting this to a time series with `xts` led me to several posts asking how to convert a database to a time series, where every day is a row in the variable Date, but in this dataframe it seems as though the each date is a variable.

I don't necessarily need to get this formatted as a time series, but I would like to plot over time the number of cases.

---

Here is a way to bypass timeseries:

```
require(RCurl)
require(foreign)
x = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv")
corona = read.csv(text = x, sep =",",header = T)
str(corona)
Italy <- corona[,corona$Country.Region=='Italy']
Italy <- corona[corona$Country.Region=='Italy',][1,5:ncol(corona)]
Italy <- as.matrix(sapply(Italy, as.numeric))
plot(Italy[,1],typ='l',xlab='', ylab='', col='red', lwd=3,
     main="Italy Cov-19 cum cases")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `xts` and plot

```
library(xts)
plot(xts(unlist(Italy), order.by = as.Date(sub("X", "", names(Italy)),
        "%m.%d.%y")), , main = "xts plot")
```

[image]

---

Some values are 0, so converting those to `NA` as it can lead to `Inf` values when the `log2` conversion is done

```
library(dplyr)
plot(xts(log(na_if(unlist(Italy), 0), 2), order.by = as.Date(sub("X", "", names(Italy)),
     "%m.%d.%y")), main = 'xts log2 plot')
```

[image]

Comment: This seems very direct and easy. Any way of doing log base 2, and precluding the ugly title of the plot generated when running the code?

Comment: @Mathstunned you can specify the `main` argument. updated

Comment: Where do you indicate log2()?

Comment: @Mathstunned Some values are 0, which would be Inf when the logs are taken.  What do you want that values to be

Comment: One final question, can you change the values on the y axis to the actual number of cases?

Comment: @Mathstunned wouldn't that be confusing when the log values are taken

Comment: Yes, What I am asking (BTW +1 for your answer so far) is to have the number of cases in the y axis, as opposed to the log2 of the cases, which is the actual plot. There has to be a `log y` function of sorts...

Comment: See this https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Log-linear_plot_of_coronavirus_cases_with_linear_regressions.png

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `tidyverse`.

First, I use `read_csv` to diretly read in the csv file (the warning tells you the classes of the columns, which you can copy to the command, as all data classes were guessed correctly):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv")
```

The dates are stored as column names. I use `pivot_longer` to transform into a long format. Once the dates are in the new column `dates`, we can use `lubridate::mdy` (mdy = month/day/year) to transform into a proper date format:

```
data_long <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(`Province/State`, `Country/Region`, Lat, Long),
               names_to = "date",
               values_to = "cases") %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(date))
```

Now we can subset the data for Italy and plot:

```
data_long_ital <- data_long %>% 
  filter(`Country/Region` == "Italy")

ggplot(data_long_ital, aes(x = date, y = cases, group = `Country/Region`))+
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 weeks")
```

[image]

Comment: Pushing the envelop ;-) Can you do log base 2?